# Delete a file from database and file system

Tags: c#, entity-framework, file

I have a table that references files in a shared location on our network (stores the file path in the database).

I have a button that needs to delete the record from the database and the file off the File System:

```
foreach (var report in reports)
{
      string filePath = report.ReportPath;

      if (File.Exists(filePath));
      {
         File.Delete(filePath);
      }                      

      context.ReportGenerations.DeleteObject(report);
      context.SaveChanges();
}
```

An exception could be thrown when deleting the file or deleting the database record and if this happens I would like neither of the operations to complete.

Is there an easy way to ensure both operations are carried out successfully?

Comment: You could wrap the code on a database transaction....

Comment: A database transaction won't roll back the deletion of the file.

Comment: well, yes, but if the db delete AND the file delete both succeed, then you wont have to rollback the transaction. check @Claudio's answer below.

Comment: What Exception did you get ?

Comment: @cyb I haven't got an exception but I might get UnathorizedAccessException when deleting the file, and there is also the possibility that the file may not be found if the record in the db is incorrect

Comment: Does deleting the record and the file have to be atomic for **all** reports?

Comment: @TimB good question...no if some reports fail it should continue deleting the others

Comment: Is the goal transaction synchronicity or eventual consistency? In other words, is it okay that there may be a short period where only one or the two items (db record, file) exists? If so, you might consider an asynchronous process like a periodic file purge job.

Comment: @neontapir another good question...for my requirements its fine that only one of the 2 exist for a short period of time

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to do 2 two things

- Wrap the whole process inside a database transaction.
- Delete file from database **before** doing it from file system

If the process fails deleting from database, physical file won't be removed as you haven't reached file system delete logic.

If the process fails deleting from file system you rollback transaction and database operation is reverted.

```
DbTransaction transaction = null;
foreach (var report in reports)
{
    try
    {
        transaction = context.Connection.BeginTransaction();

        context.ReportGenerations.DeleteObject(report);
        context.SaveChanges();

        string filePath = report.ReportPath;
        if (File.Exists(filePath));
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

---

While I believe this is the safer approach you can implement wihout getting really complex I agree that there is no synchronous approach that guarantee 100% of efficacy. To be sure that no orphan item remains, you'll have to implement a background clean up process. You'll have to analyze if such an extra complexity is justified or not according your scenario.

Comment: The 2nd item does not apply. What would happen if the file 's locked, the network's unavailable, etc etc?

Comment: It does matter: If you did the file first, and then the database call failed, how do you "rollback" the file delete?  If you do database call first, you can roll it back if you find out that deleting the file failed.

Comment: Yes, I now see I got it wrong: I thought it was "either - or", where it was both things. My mistake.

Comment: This still isn't foolproof; what happens if transaction.Commit() fails? That seems just as likely as failing to delete a file from the filesystem.

Comment: @Claudio thanks for a great answer...as a small aside you need to ensure the connection is open before assigning it to the transaction

Comment: @David then run the process again. You only need to guarantee that every row in the database points to an **existing** file in storage. If commit fails, then both the row and file exists.

Comment: One caveat of this method is that to clean the file storage, the file must contain all information that identify whether its parent (row) was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the file from database and file system in a transaction:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScope.Required, 
 new TransactionOptions 
     { IsolationLevel = IsolationLEvel.ReadCommitted}))
{
   try 
   {
       // Delete file from database
       // Delete physical file 
       // commit
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       // no commit, so database deletion will be rolled back
   }       
}
```

If the deletion of the file on a physical drive fails for some reason, the database deletion will be rolled back too.

If the deletion in the database failed, the file won't be deleted physically.

Commit is only executed if both physical delete and database delete has succeeeded.

So whatever exception might occur; you end up in a consistent state.

Comment: I know. :) I just wanted to see the `catch` clause for consistnecy 's sake.

Comment: Fail safe but this solution requires elevating the transaction to MSDTC

Comment: Ok, but is this a problem if you get fail safe solution?

Comment: @L-Three not for me, but there's a mountain of SO questions relating to MSDTC. And this may not work on Azure.

Comment: This method does not work if the program crashes during the commit line. The most common way this occurs is user kills the program or the database connection is lost at that step.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var report in reports)
{
      string filePath = report.ReportPath;
      string copyPath = @"C:\temp\tempFile.txt"
      try
      {
           if (File.Exists(filePath));
           {
              File.Copy(filePath, copyPath);
              File.Delete(filePath);
           }                      

           context.ReportGenerations.DeleteObject(report);
           context.SaveChanges();               
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
           File.Copy(copyPath, filePath);
      }
      File.Delete(copyPath);
}
```

Instead of using .txt you can also use the FileInfo to get filePath extension if they will all be different, or Split on '.' and take split[1] value and append to the end of copyPath. Up to you

Comment: I am missing a " after .txt

Comment: also missing the File.Copy(filePath, copyPath); in the try to populate the copyPath first. Sorry for missing things.

Comment: This method does not require MSDTC which is a good thing, but is not full proof e.g. the file copy back could fail.

Answer (score 0):

[.NET Transactional File Manager](http://transactionalfilemgr.codeplex.com/) looks like it could be useful for what you are trying to do. The examples seem to indicate that you can tie a database operation and a file operation together into a single transaction. I have never used it, so I can't say for certain.

Edit:
I looked at the source code, and this library does nothing special. For a delete transaction, it just does a copy, then delete, like some others have suggested here.

Answer (score -1):

The solution would be
 
1) Copy the file to other temp location and then delete.
2) On successful deletion,then delete the record from the DB.
3) If some exception thrown from the DB,copy back the file and delete the file from temp  location.
4) If evrything is successful ,then clear the file from temp location.

Comment: -1: How would that be better than wrapping the code in a transaction?

Comment: What if the file is large? It could take a long time to copy, and you now have to consider free disk space, and whether the process is able to write to a temporary location.

Comment: This is not fail safe at all. The copy back to orignal location could fail.