# Entity Framework: Call a function after an object is removed from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC project that allows the user to upload files to the server, and associate them with another object

```cs
public class FileAttachment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Donor")]
    public int DonorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Donor Donor { get; set; }
}

public class Donor
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // .....

    public virtual List<FileAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to specify a function for Entity Framework to execute when a Donor or FileAttachment object is removed from the DbSet, because the attachments are stored in the file system so I need to make sure the file gets deleted.

Comment: So is it a physical file on disk that you want to delete?

Comment: this was asked 9 hours ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214008/delete-a-file-from-database-and-file-system

Answer (score 1):

Databases don't typically call applications to notify when their data changes. It would be much easier if you design your database so *it* is managing the attachment files, not your application.

I'm not sure what database you're using, but if you're using Microsoft SQL Server, you should look into using the [FileStream data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx).